# Angular form change detection

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic3, angular-forms

I am using Angular forms, and I would like to use their built-in change detection to implement a functionality in my application. When a user clicks a button, he should only see a dialog if he/she has made any changes in the form.

I have changesMade variable:

```
private changesMade: boolean;
```

This is my TS code of the form:

```
this.carForm = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl('', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'),
            Validators.minLength(1),
            Validators.maxLength(10)
        ])});
```

This is my HTML code of the form:

```
<form [formGroup]="carForm">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label  stacked>car name</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="carname" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
</form>
```

Here is my simulated(for now) service call where I subscribe to form changes after I've set the value of carname, which is bound to the input

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  this.carname = "BMW";
  this.carForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  this.changesMade = true;
    });
}, 44)
```

The problem here is that even though I haven't touched the form, this.changesMade gets set to true.

NOTE: If I move the subscribe part of the code in the ngAfterViewInit, it still sets the changesMade to true even though I haven't toushed the input:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    //simulated server call
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.carname = "BMW";

    }, 44)
  }
      ngAfterViewInit(){
this.carForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this.changesMade = true;
        });
    }
```

I have created a [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kc655w?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts) demonstrating the problem. How can I make it execute `this.changesMade = true;` only when I've actually physically touched the input in the UI?

Comment: Why are using manually setting this.carname = "BMW"? Since you are setting this value change detection is getting triggered and your flag become true. Remove [(ngModel)]="carname" if you are using reactive forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by putting the subscription at the end of the callstack (with setTimeout(0)) everything seems to be working as expected:

```
//simulated server call
setTimeout(()=>{
  this.carname = "BMW";
  setTimeout(function(){
  this.carForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  this.changesMade = true;
    });
  }.bind(this), 0)

}, 44)
```

Here is a [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-7bbjry?file=pages/home/home.ts) demonstrating that it works.

**UPDATE**

Since using reactive forms with ngModel is [deprecated in Angular 6+](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel), it's better to replace the reactive forms with template driven forms in similar use cases.

Answer (score 6):

You use two approach in one form:

- [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)
- [Template Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

You need to select one.

**This solution with reactive forms:**

1.Remove ngModel from template

```
<ion-input type="text" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
```

2.Add [rxjs/first](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-first) for update changesMade once and auto unsubscribe

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
```

3.Remove carName property from you component and update from with [patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#patchvalue)

```
ngOnInit() {
  //simulated server call
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.carForm.patchValue({ name: 'BMW' })
    this.carForm.valueChanges.first().subscribe(val => {
      this.changesMade = true;
    });
  }, 44)
}
```

[**Stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mavjkj?file=pages/home/home.ts)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you  are mixing reactive forms and `ngModel`. Since you have used `ngModel` in your template and setting `this.carName = 'BMW'` in your component, this triggers the change detection  and the `formGroup` gets updated and your `changesMade` flag becomes true. Remove the `ngModel` and get your form values using reactive form APIs: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#reactive-forms-api.

I have updated the STACKBLITZ: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qkjeu6?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Comment: Yes, but I am subscribing to value changes AFTER i've changed the car name to "BMW". I do also need to bind my form to the model, so this is not really an option